# Two functions on the same graph, in Excel (X's don't match)

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I want to graph two functions on the same graph in Excel. The functions don't have the same values for X's (but they are close). Further, I have 5 points (pairs) for the first function and 7 points (pairs) for the second function. How can I put both of them on the same graph?

Comment: Please show what you have tried, what code you have, and state what isn't working.

Answer (score 3):

First, select the appropriate chart type: It should be an XY scatter plot:

- Right-click the chart > Chart Type... > Make sure to select XY scatter (and whatever sub-type suits you)

Then, add any number of series to your chart.

- Right-click the chart > Source Data... > Series > Add > Indicate the ranges where your X and Y values are.
- Repeat as needed.